# VBA - Is it safe to remove items from a dictionary within a for each?

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

So, I'm completely inexperienced with VBA (Visual Basic For Applications).

Basically, I have code that runs through dictionaries and removes certain elements from them. Here's a quick examples (that is NOT in the production code):

```
Dim testDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

testDict.Add 1, 5
testDict.Add 2, 10
testDict.Add 3, 15
testDict.Add 4, 20
testDict.Add 5, 25
testDict.Add 6, 30

Dim Key As Variant

For Each Key In testDict.Keys()
    If testDict.Item(Key) = 5 Then
        testDict.Remove (Key)
    End If

    If testDict.Item(Key) = 20 Then
        testDict.Remove (Key)
    End If
Next Key
```

I know that in some languages, this will throw off the underlying iterator. However I have no experience in Visual Basic, so I don't know how it works.

The reason I'm asking is that the above code works perfectly fine, and the algorithm which uses this approach works just fine too. I just need to have verified that this is a safe practice in VBA, and if not, how are cases like these usually dealt with in VBA?

Comment: This may be a good question for [codereview.se], so long as: **(A)** _the code works_, **and (B)** _it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way_. Please read the [on-topic guide](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting, if you choose to go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you have any questions or concerns, join us at our [CR Help Desk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34045).

Comment: This seems like a hypothetical question, which are off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @Quill This is definitely not a hypothetical question? The above code is compiled and verified to work, and the question specifically states that it works and if it is a safe practice :)

Comment: Your question is a hypothetical question stating _is it a safe practice to do x_. I'm not saying the code is hypothetical.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman simply because a question may be _better_ for another site is not a reason to close. Asking questions about side affects and code safety is on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Quill What could I do in order to improve the question for either website? All I want to know is if removing entries from a dictionary in VBA during a for each loop (like the working code above) can cause undesired side-effects (because of iterators), which I definitely feel like is something that can be answered quite objectively?

Comment: This question is on-topic for Stack Overflow, as given by the first on-topic reason: [_the question is on-topic if it's about: a specific programming problem_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Quill Thank you :) I was about to say this is all very quite unreasonable as I also feel it is very much on-topic.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman "Is this safe?" is a question that is on-topic for Stack Overflow, and far from a request for open-ended critique. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) and [this discussion of proper closure procedures for code review requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313266/1157100).

Comment: retracting my close vote. thanks all for the education :) Apologies for any confusion or misunderstanding I put anyone through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line illustrates the problem with this approach.

Just referring to `testDict.Item(Key)` will create a key if it doesn't exist, so you should always use `testDict.Exists(Key)` before trying to check the value of a key which may not be present.

As for making deletions while looping over the keys, if you want to be sure then start by grabbing a copy of the keys and loop over that...

Added: if you *add* an item inside the loop it will not show up as a value of `Key` variable.

```
Sub TT()

    Dim testDict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    testDict.Add 1, 5
    testDict.Add 2, 10
    testDict.Add 3, 15
    testDict.Add 4, 20
    testDict.Add 5, 25
    testDict.Add 6, 30

    Dim Key As Variant

    For Each Key In testDict.Keys()
        If testDict.Item(Key) = 5 Then
            testDict.Remove (Key)
            Debug.Print "Removed ", Key
        End If

        If testDict.Item(Key) = 20 Then
            testDict.Remove (Key)
            Debug.Print "Removed ", Key
        End If
    Next Key
    '>>> Removed        1 
    '>>> Removed        4 


    Debug.Print Join(testDict.Keys, ",")
     '>>>  2,3,5,6,1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim! Thanks for the reply :) Okay, so is it best to check if a key exists in the dictionary before using item? Or should another method be used to access an item by key?

Also, for clarification, is removing elements from the dictionary during a for each a safe operation?

I will accept the answer once the clarifications are made :) And thank you again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first IF check of key value, he doesn't need to check if it exists because the key variable is being filled in through the loop. It has no other choice but to exist. However in the second IF check, he would need to check if exists because the key could have been removed from the dictionary in the first IF check.
Besides this, as far as I can tell the code works fine.